# How does a funeral undertaker make money?

Tags: the-ballad-of-buster-scruggs

In the movie, the Ballad of Buster Scruggs, when Buster Scruggs is about to have his last duel, he says:

> Another young fellow has something to prove, I gonna set myself up in the undertaking business, stop doing all the skilled works so another man can profit.

My taking of his statement is:

- Funeral undertakers, who wear black suits, make a profit by burying people who are killed in a western gun-slinger duel.

Who is paying undertakers? What happens if there is no relative / friend present to the recently deceased gun slinger? Is it historically accurate?

Comment: What do you mean, "Who is paying undertakers?" You do know that funerals aren't free, right?

Comment: Them fancy duds ain't free. And them shootin' irons'll fetch a purty penny, I reckons.

Comment: Though it is important to note that Wild West duels are largely a myth and only a handful were ever recorded.

Comment: Inspired by your comment @jeffronicus, I've expanded my answer :)

Comment: Where is your own research? Even in the movies, have you not seen how the town or county authorities pick up the bill? Here in the UK, such funerals were traditionally - and still might be - referred to as being buried 'in a pauper's grave…' The phrase never needed to state 'because the deceased or the family were too poor to foot the bill…'

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Funeral undertakers, who wear black suits, make a profit by burying people **who are killed in a western gun-slinger duel**. (emphasis mine)

I'd rather say: **Funeral undertakers make a profit by burying people.** No matter how you die.

[The ballad of Buster Scruggs](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6412452/) takes place after the [American Civil War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Civil_War). At that time, [funeral undertaking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funeral_director) was already a [business](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_care_industry_in_the_United_States) in the [United States](https://blogs.loc.gov/law/2022/09/evolution-of-american-funerary-customs-and-laws/):

> In the 19th century, most undertakers made furniture or cabinets. They expanded their lines to include wooden coffins or caskets.

After someone died, in the event that no one would pay for the funeral, you still had community service or mutual aid (or even *post mortem business*<sup>1</sup>). You had a need for help, be it for personal, religious, educational or health reasons:

> In early America, home funerals were the practice everywhere, and each community had a group of women who came in to help with the (laying out of the dead). [Funeral homes in the 1800’s](https://blog.htmayfuneralhome.com/2016/08/funeral-homes/)

More to read if you're looking for in-depth historical accuracy:

1. [Death and burials in early America](https://clements.umich.edu/exhibit/death-in-early-america/burials/)
2. [Undertakers and Hearses](https://clements.umich.edu/exhibit/death-in-early-america/undertakers/)
3. [Funerals and Burial Practices](https://philadelphiaencyclopedia.org/essays/funerals-and-burial-practices/)

---

<sup>1. *“No, I mean how much are you going to make on the deal? Aw, Beckum, you’re going to do to me what they did to John Wesley Hardin.  You’re going to lay me out, let the public come by to gawk at me for 50 cents a head, 10 cents for the children. When the curiosity peters out, you’re going to stuff me in a gunny sack and stick me in a hole, while you hurry to the bank with your loot.”* [U.S. Undertakers in the 1800s](https://agoodgoodbye.com/trends-in-death-care/u-s-undertakers-in-the-1800s/)</sup>

---

**About gunfights**:

> How common were gunfights in the American West? If we’re talking about a quick-draw duel, like the ones in movie westerns, it almost never happened. Now, if we’re talking about the use of firearms in personal disputes in the American West, that was much more common, though a victim was more likely to be shot in the back. The idea was to “get the drop” on your enemy. [Yale University](https://news.yale.edu/2015/07/21/gunfights-us-colonialism-and-studying-american-west-east-coast)

Most gunslingers would approach a target gun in hand, cocked, and fire from as close as possible. Usually from behind to limit the chances of retaliation. "*It's also worth noting that many Old West towns had fairly strict gun control regulations: [Gun control is as old as the Old West](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/history/gun-control-old-west-180968013/).*"<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>2. Credit goes to this [comment](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/121388/how-does-a-funeral-undertaker-make-money/121389#comment215030_121389) by [Flydog57](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/83638/flydog57)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, answered my question clearly. I was wondering what would happen to a lone-wolf gunslinger's body after he was killed and there was no money on his body to pay for his own burial.

Comment: It's also worth noting that many _Old West_ towns had fairly strict gun control regulations: https://www.smithsonianmag.com/history/gun-control-old-west-180968013/

Comment: Nobody wants a decaying corpse left on the street, so the local government or a committee of citizens would step in an arrange for burial. Perhaps not involving the undertaker, or perhaps paying them a minimal fee for digging the grave, but not providing a casket, embalming, or a religious service. See [Potter's Field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potter's_field)